# Oracle SQL REGEXP_REPLACE - Everything Except Specified String

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am having an issue with something that I thought would have been simple, but can't for the life of me get it sorted out. I'm trying to replace everything *except* a specified string with a blank space.

I am able to remove the string (see below), but am unable to 'inverse' the operation.

```
with text as (
select 'Cat dog sheep /* 67 = 123 + monkey12 abcd and then a fish B1234.CAT_DOG_MOUSE and half a loaf of bread /* ON INNER JOIN B3456.BIRD_SHOE 11' as jibberish)
    
select regexp_replace(jibberish, '(B)[[:digit:]]{4}[.][[:alnum:]_]+', ' ') as new_text from text;

'Cat dog sheep /* 67 = 123 + monkey12 abcd and then a fish   and half a loaf of bread /* ON INNER JOIN   11'
```

I have tried various things, such as '[^(B)[[:digit:]]{4}[.][[:alnum:]_]+]*' and various other things that I've found on here, but none of them seem to work.
Is this is a quirk of using regex within Oracle?

Just to clarify, after running the code I would be wanting something that looked like this:

```
'              B1234.CAT_DOG_MOUSE                 B3456.BIRD_SHOE       '
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So, you replace the matches and expect them to remain in the output? This is impossible. Either extract, or match all but what your pattern matches.

Comment: Use a capture group in the regexp, and a back-reference in the replacement string. See the example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(jibberish, '(B\d{4}\.\w+)?.', '\1 ')`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan 'from dual'

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sql
regexp_replace(jibberish, '(B\d{4}\.\w+)?.', '\1 ')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WS74T0/1).

*Details*

- `(B\d{4}\.\w+)?` - an optional group matching `B`, then four digits, a dot and then one or more word chars
- `.` - any one char.

The replacement is `\1`, the backreference to the value captured by the capturing group.

**If there can be consecutive matches**, add one more `REGEXP_REPLACE` call to append a space right after your expected matches as a workaround:

```sql
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(jibberish, '(B\d{4}\.\w+)', '\1 '), '(B\d{4}\.\w+)?.', '\1 ')
```

This might add a couple extract spaces, though, but all consecutive matches will be found.

Comment: In my answer (posted a few minutes before yours) I indicated already a "special case" when your solution will not give the expected result: if two "keep" substrings exists back-to-back with no characters separating them. Other than that your solution is identical to mine.

Comment: @mathguy Ok, I just posted it because OP confirmed [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340743/oracle-sql-regexp-replace-everything-except-specified-string/66341970?noredirect=1#comment117284996_66340743) worked. It was there long before you posted the answer.

Comment: Oh - OK, I didn't notice; I see it now. In any case, my solution is wrong - since the beginning of a new "keep" fragment will be consumed by the end of the first. If such fragments may appear back-to-back, a different solution is needed.

Comment: @mathguy I think it is evident: just add another `regexp_replace`: `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(jibberish, '(B\d{4}\.\w+)', '\1 '), '(B\d{4}\.\w+)?.', '\1 ')`. This might add an extra space or two to the string, but all consecutive matches will be found.

Comment: Actually on further thought, what is evident is that my "special case" with two back-to-back occurrences is wrong from the beginning. If we accept the strict interpretation of the OP's attempt, there can't be two back-to-back occurrences; the Bnnnn part from the second must be considered the end of the first occurrence, so there can't be a "second occurrence" immediately following. Whether the OP actually meant that, only he knows.